# Can't setup dynamic links with custom domain linked to Squarespace

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, squarespace

I'm having issues setting dynamic links with a custom domain. My domain is from Google Domains, and it's linked to a Squarespace site. When I try to add the A records to my domain on Google Domains ... it says the records already exist. And I can't figure out how to override or remove them. Or if that will mess up my linkage to Squarespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few of things I was missing, with great help from the Firebase slack channel:

First, You can't use the same domain as your Squarespace domain. You'll need to create a subdomain. I used link.???.com

Second, when I changed the DNS settings, Firebase instructions ask you to add two A records. But the second always fails saying it already exists. Support folks said you only need one, the second is for redundancy. Instructions should state this!

Next, I was missing steps 1 and 3 in these [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app). For step 3, make sure you create the property as an array.